# Getting an error with the scroll controller

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm navigating from the current screen and get back to the same screen after fetching the data. I'm getting the following error when the widget tree is being re-rendered.

```
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 113 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Please find the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:netapp/commons/dependencies.dart';
import 'package:netapp/models/content_model.dart';
import 'package:netapp/screens/load_content.dart';
import 'package:netapp/services/services.dart';

import '../widgets/custom_content_blocks.dart';

String topicID;

List<ContentData> contentList = [];

int count = 0;
double incrementSize = 1 / contentList.length;
double piCurrentValue = 0.0;

List<Widget> pageContents = [];

DatabaseService dbService = DatabaseService();

ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

scrollToBottom() {
  scrollController.animateTo(
    scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
  );
}

class ContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentContentID;
  final String title;
  final List<ContentData> content;
  final String nextContentID;

  ContentPage({
    this.currentContentID,
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.nextContentID,
  });

  @override
  _ContentPageState createState() => _ContentPageState();
}

class _ContentPageState extends State<ContentPage> {
  void moveToNextItem() {
    setState(
      () {
        count += 1;
        if (count <= contentList.length - 1) {
          piCurrentValue = piCurrentValue + incrementSize;
          if (contentList[count].contentType == 'TXT') {
            pageContents
                .add(TextBlock(displayText: contentList[count].contentText));
          } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'IMP') {
            pageContents
                .add(ImpBlock(displayText: contentList[count].contentText));
          } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'TIP') {
            pageContents
                .add(TipBlock(displayText: contentList[count].contentText));
          } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'CODE') {
            pageContents.add(CodeBlock(
                codeText: contentList[count].contentCodeText,
                codeCaption: contentList[count].contentCodeCaption));
          } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'PNG') {
            pageContents.add(ImageBlock(
                imageFilename: contentList[count].contentImageFilename,
                imageCaption: contentList[count].contentImageCaption));
          } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'SVG') {
            pageContents.add(SvgBlock(
                svgFilename: contentList[count].contentImageFilename,
                svgCaption: contentList[count].contentImageCaption));
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    contentList = widget.content;
    if (pageContents.length >= 0) {
      pageContents = [];
      count = 0;
      incrementSize = 1 / contentList.length;
      piCurrentValue = incrementSize;
      if (contentList[count].contentType == 'TXT') {
        pageContents
            .add(TextBlock(displayText: contentList[count].contentText));
      } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'IMP') {
        pageContents.add(ImpBlock(displayText: contentList[count].contentText));
      } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'TIP') {
        pageContents.add(TipBlock(displayText: contentList[count].contentText));
      } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'CODE') {
        pageContents.add(CodeBlock(
            codeText: contentList[count].contentCodeText,
            codeCaption: contentList[count].contentCodeCaption));
      } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'PNG') {
        pageContents.add(ImageBlock(
            imageFilename: contentList[count].contentImageFilename,
            imageCaption: contentList[count].contentImageCaption));
      } else if (contentList[count].contentType == 'SVG') {
        pageContents.add(SvgBlock(
            svgFilename: contentList[count].contentImageFilename,
            svgCaption: contentList[count].contentImageCaption));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    scrollController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => scrollToBottom());

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF181632),
        body: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: moveToNextItem,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      widget.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue.shade300,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 12.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          strokeWidth: 2.5,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          value: piCurrentValue,
                          valueColor:
                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  controller: scrollController,
                  reverse: false,
                  children: List.unmodifiable(pageContents),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      color: count < contentList.length - 1
                          ? Colors.blue.shade700
                          : Colors.green.shade700,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: count < contentList.length - 1
                            ? null
                            : () {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => LoadContent(
                                        contentID: widget.nextContentID),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                        child: Text(
                          count < contentList.length - 1
                              ? 'HIT'
                              : 'NEXT LEVEL',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: count < contentList.length - 1
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I did check out a few solutions that are already present, but couldn't be of much help.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me fix this issue.

Comment: You can't use the same ScrollController for multiple ScrollViews. You can only attach a ScrollController to one Scroll View

Answer (score 0):

Move the below code within the _ContentPageState resolved the issue :)

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

scrollToBottom() {
  scrollController.animateTo(
    scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
  );
}
```